# Assertj: How to compare 2 objects list by objects content?

Tags: java, assertj

Given the following (quick and missing) code:

```
class Pair{
int x;
int y;
}

List l1 = Arrays.asList(new Match(1,2), new Match(1,3), new Match(2,3));
List l2 = Arrays.asList(new Match(1,2), new Match(1,3), new Match(2,3));
```

How can I compare the content of the lists?
Everything I used so far checked if the objects themselves were equal and not the objects value:

```
assertThat(l1).isEqualTo(l2);
assertThat(l1).containsAll(l2);
assertThat(l1).containsExactly(values);
assertThat(l1).containsExactlyElementsOf(iterable);
```

Must I implement equals() method for Match class?

May this be the correct way?

```
for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++){
    assertThat(l1.get(i)).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTol2.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Give a try to `usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator(recursiveConfiguration)`, it enables recursive comparison to all iterable assertions.

Ex:

```java
public class Person {
  String name;
  boolean hasPhd;
}

public class Doctor {
  String name;
  boolean hasPhd;
}

Doctor drSheldon = new Doctor("Sheldon Cooper", true);
Doctor drLeonard = new Doctor("Leonard Hofstadter", true);
Doctor drRaj = new Doctor("Raj Koothrappali", true);

Person sheldon = new Person("Sheldon Cooper", false);
Person leonard = new Person("Leonard Hofstadter", false);
Person raj = new Person("Raj Koothrappali", false);
Person howard = new Person("Howard Wolowitz", false);

List<Doctor> doctors = list(drSheldon, drLeonard, drRaj);
List<Person> people = list(sheldon, leonard, raj);

RecursiveComparisonConfiguration configuration = RecursiveComparisonConfiguration.builder()
                                                                                 .withIgnoredFields("hasPhd")
                                                                                 .build();

// assertion succeeds as both lists contains equivalent items in order.
assertThat(doctors).usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator(configuration)
                   .contains(sheldon);
```

See https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison-for-iterable  for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: When trying this one the compiler is expecting a Doctor object for the contains() method.

Comment: Looks like we need to cast the list
```assertThat((List) doctors).usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator(configuration)
                .contains(sheldon);```

Comment: Found better
```assertThat(doctors).asList().usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator(configuration).contains(sheldon);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should override `equals()` and `hashCode()`

Comment: That's correct. See the javadoc of equals() and hashCode() : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, so after further researching I would recommend:

```
for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++){
    assertThat(l1.get(i)).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTol2.get(i));
}
```

You can read the details:

https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison

Answer (score 1):

Using [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html):

```java
assertThat(actualModel)
                    .usingRecursiveComparison()
                    ...variousOtherOptions()
                    .isEqualTo(expectedModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

@vincentdep is correct. If you are using Java 14 or above, you can use a `record` class:

```java
public record Pair(int x, int y){};

List l1 = Arrays.asList(new Pair(1,2), new Pair(1,3), new Pair(2,3));
List l2 = Arrays.asList(new Pair(1,2), new Pair(1,3), new Pair(2,3));

assertThat(l1).isEqualTo(l2);
assertThat(l1).containsAll(l2);
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using Java 11.

Comment: I suggest trying the latest versions, it's fun! If you cannot, you have to override equals and hashCode or use a library to do it for you. Project Lombok would generate them while Apache Commons provides methods you can call.